# ExtJS: Rendering an image to an existing div

Tags: javascript, extjs

I am using ExtJS in a rather complex UI project. I have a config object similar to this:

```
{
    xtype: 'component',
    html: "<a href='some link'>some text</a><div id='someDivId'/>"
}
```

Further down in my function I create an image like this: `Ext.create('Ext.Img', {/* image config */});`

How do I put the image generated by `Ext.create` into the DOM element `someDivId`?

Comment: Please show implementation for Ext.Img

Comment: @user3735633 My mistake, replaced with `Ext.create`

Comment: Are you using `RenderTo:` ?

Comment: @user3735633 yes. I was using it incorrectly due partially to using the wrong creation function - I thought `Ext.Img()` was shorthand for `Ext.create('Ext.Img', {})`. If you want to post this as an answer I'll accept it.

Comment: Don't do that. It will create a memory leak.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need is the `renderTo` config.

```
Ext.create( 'Ext.Img',
    {
        ...
        renderTo: 'someDivId' // you can use IDs directly, HTML elements and Ext elements
    } );
```

Documentation: http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.3/#!/api/Ext.Img-cfg-renderTo

Comment: The original poster already stated he was using `renderTo`, but was using the incorrect method.

Comment: I believe this is the correct answer to the question at hand "How to put an image into a DOM element using ID"

Answer (score -1):

Use `Ext.create('Ext.Img', {})` instead of `Ext.Img()`.

Comment: Those are functionally equivalent. Also you didn't post a reason why to use one over the other.

Comment: Read the comments above @EvanTrimboli and maybe you shouldn't be so quick to downvote.

Comment: Ok, so your answer is no longer relevant. Also you still didn't explain it. Also didn't say that `new Ext.Img()` would have worked.

Comment: How does it work then? Post an answer. Don't down someone else if you can answer it better

Comment: How does what work? So if I post an answer I'm allowed to downvote? ;)

Comment: Just saying... Stack Overflow is built on the principle of being constructive and providing knowledge where knowledge is needed.

Comment: Fine, but I explained why I didn't think your answer helps. How is that not constructive? My comment was even longer than your answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79250/discussion-between-user3735633-and-evan-trimboli).